# For loop breaks after first loop (Laravel Controller)

Tags: php, for-loop, laravel-8

I was trying to make a function that calculates the correct answers after a user answers a quiz.  The function runs after the user answers all the questions and clicks the Submit button.

The quiz has 10 questions in the DB, but users can only take 5 questions in random order per exam.
The function keeps returning that there is only 1 correct answer even though I answer all 5 questions correctly. I have also performed dd() on all the variables,requests and gets and they show the desired values, So I am assuming that the loop runs once and then breaks, but what could've caused it?

In  ExamController:

```
public function calculateResults(){
        // variable that is incremented per correct answer
        $totalCorrect = 0;
        // array of ids of the questions the user has taken (out of 10 questions in DB, only 5 
           questions in random order are taken by the user
        $takenQuestions = request()->input('taken_questions');
      //array of answers provided by user (multiple choice)
        $givenAnswers = request()->input('answer');
        // get exam id 
        $exam_id = request()->input('exam_id');
        // get all exam questions from DB
        $examQuestions = examQuestion::where('exam_id',$exam_id);


        // loop through each question that was available in the exam
        for($i = 1; $i<=count($takenQuestions);$i++){
            // get the question  from the exam DB that matches the questions taken by the user
            $givenQuestion = $examQuestions->find($takenQuestions[$i]);
            
            //if questions match
            if(isset($givenQuestion)){
                // get the question's correct answer
                $correctAnswer = $givenQuestion->answers->firstWhere('isCorrect',true);
                
                //check if the correct answer and user's given answer matches
                if($correctAnswer->content == $givenAnswers[$i]){
                    //if they match increment correct answer variable
                    $totalCorrect++;
                }
           }
        }

        dd($totalCorrect);
}
```

I have checked and performed `dd()` and `echo` on the following:

- `count($takenQuestions)` in the second condition of the for loop returns 5 as desired (So this can't be the cause)
- `$i` returns as 1 (as desired) in the first loop and then the echo command doesn't repeat.
- EDIT: `$takenQuestions` returns the array of the `question IDs` of the 5 questions that the user answered in the exam (they are selected randomly)
  Example when I `dd($takenQuestions)`

```
Taken Questions:
array:5 [▼
  1 => "1"
  2 => "2"
  3 => "3"
  4 => "5"
  5 => "10"
]
```

Meaning questions with the Question Id 1,2,3,5,10 were the questions that the user answered

Comment: what is the value of `$takenQuestions`? can you `dd($takenQuestions)`

Comment: `$takenQuestions` returns the array of the `question IDs` of the 5 questions that the user answered in the exam (they are selected randomly)
`
Taken Questions:
array:5 [▼
  1 => "1"
  2 => "2"
  3 => "3"
  4 => "5"
  5 => "10"
]
`
Meaning questions with the Question Id 1,2,3,5,10 were the questions that the user answered

Answer (score 1):

What's the content of your `$givenAnswers` variable?

Is it indexed in the same order as the questions (so 1,2,3,4,5) or is it indexed by the question IDs (1,2,3,5,10)? Your current code assumes the first, but the latter seems more likely.

If it is indexed by question ID rather than array index, your code should be:

```
if($correctAnswer->content == $givenAnswers[$takenQuestions[$i]]){
    //if they match increment correct answer variable
    $totalCorrect++;
}
```